VBA code to delete rows that are copies of each other across multiple sheets
I am writing a VBA code in order to quickly delete rows on excel that are duplicated on other sheets. For example, sheet one will have the first picture. Sheet 2 will have the second picture.
The second picture is the list of the duplicates that I need to delete from the list. Is there any specific commands or functions I can use in order to call for this? I am currently using the ".RemoveDuplicates" command but I don't know how to call that across multiple sheets and it also deletes anything that is duplicated, not from a specific list that needs to be deleted. The deletion should only be on the first sheet and not on the sheet with the list that needs to be deleted.
This is my code so far:
Sub Delete_Repeats_Macro()

    Range("B3:E20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

    Range("B3:E20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2)
   
End Sub

Sheet1



Amount
Date
Part Number
Amount




879104
11/23/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/23/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/23/2024
KAFPRNP
43


879104
11/24/2024
KAFPRNP
47


879104
11/24/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/25/2024
KAFPRNP
32


879104
11/25/2024
KAFPRNP
34


879104
11/25/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/26/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/27/2024
KAFPRNP
26


879104
11/27/2024
KAFPRNP
54


879104
11/27/2024
KAFPRNP
56



Sheet2



Amount
Date
Part Number
Amount




879104
11/23/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/23/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/24/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/25/2024
KAFPRNP
34


879104
11/25/2024
KAFPRNP
56


879104
11/27/2024
KAFPRNP
56



This lets me deleted any row if there are any repeats in the first column. What changes do I need to do in order to get the code to delete duplicates based on another sheet? Thank you in advance.
Edit: Is there a way to only delete a matching row to a limited amount of time as it's called in sheet 2? For example, I have three rows that repeat the same thing on sheet 1. I have one row on sheet 2 that repeats that exact thing. The code right now would delete all three repeats on sheet 1 when I only need for it to delete only one of those three repeats as it is only called for on sheet 2. Thank you in advance.

I added text tables for you images.  Images of data and code are frowned upon here.

Are you trying to remove duplicates on a individual worksheets?  Or do you want no item to appear in more than one worksheet?

You'll need to loop over the list on sheet2, and check each row cell-by-cell against each row on sheet1 - if you find a match on sheet1 then delete that row.  RemoveDuplicates won't work across sheets.

Why on sheet 2 are first 2 rows identical ?

The first 2 rows are identical because that is something that happens sometimes for what this application will be used for. If the row repeats 2 times on the 2nd sheet, then I will need 2 rows deleted on the first sheet. If it is repeated only 1 time on the second sheet, I will only need one of those rows deleted on the first sheet. Thank you for the question @CDP1802

@TimWilliams That code only highlights the text for me. I have started implementing a code to delete the text that is red. Is there any way to call the range command for the whole sheet?

Replace the line rngDel.Font.Color = vbRed in Tim's code with rngDel.Delete

As @Tim mentioned, the RemoveDuplicates method doesn't work across multiple worksheets. Consider using a Dictionary object to identify and handle duplicate rows on Sheet1.
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, ColCnt As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Const SEP = "|"
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify sheet name as needed
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load data from Sheet2
    arrData = oSht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ' loop throught rows
    For i = LBound(arrData)+1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = 1 To ColCnt
            ' sKey is the combination of all cells in a row
            If j=1 Then 
                sKey = arrData(i, j)
            Else
                sKey = sKey & SEP & arrData(i, j)
            End If
        Next
        objDic(sKey) = ""
    Next
    Dim delRng As Range 
    arrData = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = 1 To ColCnt
            If j = 1 Then
                sKey = arrData(i, j)
            Else
                sKey = sKey & SEP & arrData(i, j)
            End If
        Next
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then ' found duplicated row on Sheet1
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = oSht1.Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                Set delRng = Application.Union(delRng, oSht1.Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
        delRng.EntireRow.Delete ' Remove duplicated rows
    End If
End Sub


Update:

Question: The code right now would delete all three repeats on sheet 1 when I only need for it to delete only one of those three repeats as it is only called for on sheet 2.

Sub Demo2()
    Dim objDic1 As Object, objDic2 As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, ColCnt As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Const SEP = "|"
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify sheet name as needed
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set objDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load data from Sheet2
    arrData = oSht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ' loop throught rows
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = 1 To ColCnt
            ' sKey is the combination of all cells in a row
            If j = 1 Then
                sKey = arrData(i, j)
            Else
                sKey = sKey & SEP & arrData(i, j)
            End If
        Next
        If objDic2.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic2(sKey) = objDic2(sKey) + 1
        Else
            objDic2(sKey) = 1
        End If
    Next
    Dim delRng As Range
    arrData = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = 1 To ColCnt
            If j = 1 Then
                sKey = arrData(i, j)
            Else
                sKey = sKey & SEP & arrData(i, j)
            End If
        Next
        ' get the count of each row on Sheet1
        If objDic1.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic1(sKey) = objDic1(sKey) + 1
        Else
            objDic1(sKey) = 1
        End If
        If objDic2.exists(sKey) Then
            ' found extra duplicated row on Sheet1
            If objDic1(sKey) > objDic2(sKey) Then
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = oSht1.Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Application.Union(delRng, oSht1.Cells(i, 1))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
'        delRng.EntireRow.Select
        delRng.EntireRow.Delete ' Remove duplicated rows
    End If
End Sub



Microsoft documentation:

Dictionary object


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)


Application.Union method (Excel)


thank you for the response. The code works! However, I should have been clearer. The code gets rid of all of the matching rows on sheet 1 that are shown on sheet 2. However, is there a way to only delete a matching row to a limited amount of time as it's called in sheet 2? For example, I have three rows that repeat the same thing on sheet 1. I have one row on sheet 2 that repeats that exact thing. The code right now would delete all three repeats on sheet 1 when I only need for it to delete only one of those three repeats as it is only called for on sheet 2. Thank you in advance.

delete only one - Does it means only delete the 3rd one on sheet1?

It looks like you can use the dictionary value as a count of the lines on sheet2 and then only delete that number of lines on sheet 1

Pls try the revised script Demo2.

I expected you to decrement the existing dictionary value until zero.

What if I only need to use specific rows to determine what will get deleted? For example, I only need to select row H and K on sheet 2 to determine what criteria needs to be deleted from sheet 1?

Then you need to change the code to create sKey.

My 2c:
Sub DeleteDups()
    
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, r As Long
    Dim dups As Object, k As String, rngDel As Range, rw As Range
    
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    'all distinct row "keys" and counts from sheet 2
    Set dups = RowKeyCount(rng2.Offset(1).Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 1)) 'excluding headers
    
    'check each row in sheet 1
    For r = 2 To rng1.Rows.Count
        Set rw = rng1.Rows(r)
        k = RowKey(rw)
        If Len(k) > 0 And dups.Exists(k) Then 'duplicate?
            BuildRange rngDel, rw   'flag for deletion
            dups(k) = dups(k) - 1   'decrement count remaining
            If dups(k) = 0 Then dups.Remove k 'all dups handled?
        End If
    Next r
    
    'any duplicates found?
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Font.Color = vbRed 'or rngDel.Delete...
    
End Sub

'Return a dictionary of "row key" (concatenated from all values
'  in each row of `rng`) mapped to the count of each key's occurence
Function RowKeyCount(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim rw As Range, k As String, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        k = RowKey(rw)
        If Len(k) > 0 Then dict(k) = dict(k) + 1
    Next rw
    Set RowKeyCount = dict
End Function

'If rw is not empty, concatenate all values with "|"
Function RowKey(rw As Range) As String
    If Application.CountA(rw) > 0 Then
        RowKey = rw.Worksheet.Evaluate("=TextJoin(""|"",FALSE," & rw.Address & ")")
    End If
End Function

'build up a range in steps
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub


Is there a way to only call for specific columns? Such as Highlighting column H and I on the second sheet to determine what fits the criteria to be deleted in sheet 1. And also only scanning a certain row on sheet 1 to see if it needs to be deleted?

That sounds like a different question...

Yes. I was thinking, in my example, multiple rows are the same across both sheets such as the first column having the same exact number '879104' so using that column to dictate what needs to be deleted is not effective. But using columns like the Date and amount would be better as those columns have different values in each cell under the column.

I would post a new question and reference this one.

You really don't need all that VBA (if any automation, you could just do typescript). This formula works based on the assumption of sheets named Sheet1 and Sheet2 and columns B:E
=LET(functionToGrabData,LAMBDA(aRng,LET(iStart,TAKE(aRng,MATCH(9.999E+299,INDEX(aRng,,1))),DROP(BYROW(iStart,LAMBDA(aRow,(TEXTJOIN(0,FALSE,aRow)))),1))),
jFirstTab,functionToGrabData(B:E),jSecondTab,functionToGrabData(Sheet2!$B:$E),BYROW(jFirstTab,LAMBDA(iV,ISNUMBER(MATCH(iV,jSecondTab,0)))))

If you really insisted on using vba, you could drop that function into a cell, then delete all the rows in that range where the formula matches true. Since you've got an answer, I won't type it out, but really typescript would be the way to go if you wanted automation.
Here's a Typescript routine you could run every five minutes or automate on some process...
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Define sheet and column locations
    const colRange = "B:E"; 
    const keepHeader = true; //assume top row is header to keep
    const editSheetName = "Sheet1";// Replace with your sheet name
    const refSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Replace with your sheet name
    const columnAssumedToHaveValues = 0; // first column shouldn't be blank
    const secondColRange = colRange; //assumed the same
 
 
    const alphaSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(editSheetName); 
    const bravoSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(refSheetName); 

    var cleanStart = alphaSheet.getRange(colRange).getUsedRange().getValues().filter(x => x[columnAssumedToHaveValues] !== '');
    var cleanCompare = bravoSheet.getRange(secondColRange).getUsedRange().getValues().filter(x => x[columnAssumedToHaveValues] !== '');

    for (var r = cleanStart.length - 1; r > -1; r--) {
        var testRow = cleanStart[r];
        for (let t = 0; t < cleanCompare.length; t++) {
            let compareRow = cleanCompare[t];

            if( testRow.every((element, index) => element === compareRow[index])){
                cleanStart.splice(r, 1);
                cleanCompare.splice(t, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    const iStartPos = keepHeader ? 1 : 0;

    alphaSheet.getRange(colRange).getUsedRange().getOffsetRange(iStartPos,0).clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
   alphaSheet.getRange(colRange).getCell(iStartPos,0).getResizedRange(cleanStart.length-1,cleanStart[0].length-1).setValues(cleanStart);
}


